# Has there been any mission to land on a planet or moon in the Outer Solar System?

Tags: solar-system, landing, photography

Are there any planets or moons in the Outer Solar System, where a man-made object has landed and made photographs of its surface?

I can remember an article somewhere that said there's only one moon where anything has ever landed and sent pictures of the surface, but I can't remember which moon that was, and I'm also not sure that it was actually the only case.

Comment: That's strange. Even considering surface gravity there are 6 moons with at least half of our Moon's surface gravity which means that astronauts could walk there. There are more than 100 moons out there, and almost 200 known Centaur asteroids which cross tthe orbits of the outer planets.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the 'Outer Solar System'? Traditionally that means Jupiter and beyond, but if you're talking about Trans-Neptunian objects (e.g. Pluto), there's plenty of unknowns.

Comment: @john3103 Yes, but obviously there's only a few man-made objects that could ever go beyond Pluto, so I don't talk about that.

Comment: "Ever" is a very long time. Given unpredictable advances in technology over the next few thousand years, I wouldn't bet against landing a probe on the surface of Alpha Centauri (yes, I mean the star). Do you want to update your question to limit the scope to current or currently planned technology?

Comment: @KeithThompson I think, the word "could" assumes that I'm talking about things which are already sent up *in the past*, and doesn't inclue objects that we're going to be sent up *later*.

Comment: I accept that that's what you meant, but I didn't read it that way, and I still don't. I don't see a restriction to things that have already been launched in your question, and I think [orique's answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/4341/574) makes the same assumption I did. I really think your question needs to be edited to reflect what you meant to ask.

Comment: @KeithThompson I think you overcomplicate the question itself. No offense, but if you have reservations, then edit it yourself.

Comment: I don't want to edit it without being sure exactly what you're asking. Are you saying that if a Europa lander mission were launched next week, that wouldn't count as far as your question is concerned? I'm not aware of *anything* that (a) has already been launched, and (b) is capable of landing on any moon.

Comment: @KeithThompson In my view, questions that contain *until now* or *could ever* are always meant at the time when the question was asked - 24th April 2014, in this certain case. Though, answers can always be edited and added, if any change happens in the field that is related to the question. Exception is if changes happen frequently, but in this case, most certainly we don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Can you please answer my question about Europa?

Comment: No, it doesn't count. But if it happens, you'd be free to add it in an additional answer. There's no problem with it I think.

Comment: @Zoltán, I've edited the question in light of these comments.

Comment: @Hobbes thank you very much, it's pretty exactly is that I wanted to explain. Bad grammar...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In 2005 the [Huygens probe](http://sci.esa.int/cassini-huygens/47052-huygens/) successfully landed on Titan, satellite of Saturn.

My guess is that any body with a solid/liquid surface could be a suitable target. Many jovian or saturnine moons like Enceladus, Phoebe or Hyperion feature solid surfaces.

Comment: I'd also suggest that if it's just a question of landing, not surviving, you could land on any planet or moon. Even the gas giant have solid cores. You'd be destroyed before you reach them, but the crushed remains of your satellite would eventually reach them assuming it had a reasonable re-entry system.

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg crushing into a far planet doesn't have any scienticfic values - even in Kerbal Space Program neither :)

Comment: I don't know about that - I'm sure if you had some pretty hardy sensors and a RTG powered coms system you'd probably be able to transmit some information during your decent. If you could it would probably have scientific value.

Comment: In fact, Galileo probe were sent into Jupiter and transmitted useful data until it was destroyed

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt See related [How many space craft have been intentionally crashed through 2014?](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4342)

Comment: @JamesJenkins I just assumed that neither NASA or anyone else would plan for sending something into space just for getting only a little amount of information before it's destroeyed. Doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: @orique you can expand this answer to include asteroids/comets landings, [See related](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1365)